# how to print input user form in another page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

this is my form code

```
<form action="action_page.html" method="GET">
  <div>
  <label for="name">First name:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
```

This is my JavaScript print execution "action_page.html". I want this to print the form in another page.

```
<script>
    const resultsList = document.getElementById('result')
    new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value,
        name) => {
        resultsList.append('${name}: ${value}')
        resultsList.append(document.createElement('br'))

    })
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have `for="name"` three times while zero inputs actually match this name?

Comment: it was a mistake, this is the real question

Comment: so you want the form to show in the action_page.html?

Comment: yes, that is what I want

Comment: If you want to "rebuild" the form from the original page in the new `action_page.html` you will need extra metadata, like the input types and the label texts. This information is currently not transported there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by giving your form an unique ID

```
<form action="action_page.html" id="myForm" method="GET">
```

You should then add a hidden input field for the form `HTML` that you want to send.

```
<input type="hidden" id="formClone" name="form">
```

You have to use `Jquery` for this. Include that by using this code.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then add this `JS` to your page with the form

```
var clone = $('#myForm').clone();
$("#formClone").val(clone.html());
```

This clones your form and puts the form `HTML` to the input.
This then gets send as extra `URL` parameter 'form'

To add the form to your other page use this in your `action_page.html`:

```
var resultsList = {};
new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value, name) => {
    resultsList[name] = value;
});
$('body').append(resultsList["form"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jbadminton already mentioned all the script elements that are necessary for your project - apart from also filling in the already supplied values. This is what my snippet does too (in a non-jQuery way). Give it a try, here:

```js
// ============= first page ==================================================================
const [frm, fclone, srch, rcv] = "#myForm,#formClone,#search,#receive".split(",")
  .map(sel => document.querySelector(sel));

frm.onsubmit = ev => {
  ev.preventDefault(); // <===  DELETE this line in the "real" application!
  fclone.value = frm.innerHTML;
  // DELETE the following line in the "real" application:
  srch.textContent = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(frm).entries()).toString();
}

// ============= second page ===== action_page.html ==========================================
// in the "real" application this would run AFTER LOADING (not as a button click event)
rcv.onclick = _ => {
  // in the "real" application use        window.location.search  (instead of: srch.textContent)
  const entries = [...new URLSearchParams(srch.textContent).entries()];
  // take the last entry in ENTRIES and use its value as HTML for the FORM:
  const f = document.querySelector("#yourForm");
  f.innerHTML = (entries.pop() ?? ["", ""])[1];
  // now populate the values:
  entries.forEach(([nam, val]) => f[nam].value = val)
}
```

```html
<!-- sending page -->
<h1>page 1</h1>
<form action="action_page.html" id="myForm" method="GET">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">

  <input type="hidden" id="formClone" name="form">
  <button>send</button>
</form>
<br><br> This is being sent to the second page as parameters in the URL:<br>
<span id="search"></span><br>

<hr><!-- receiving page -->
<button id="receive">receive</button>
<h1>page 2</h1>
<form id="yourForm"></form>
```